# Reading value returned from a clr stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a clr stored procedure which I can execute in sql server manager and get a value returned, I am unable to replicate this in a .net application. 
in sql I execute the sp using:

```
exec  @Result = GetDistanceAndTime @Profile, '53.6924582,-2.8730636000', '53.816408201,-2.990582799997'
```

and the values (text string) '41124|4032|Ok' appears in the messages tab.

I have tried to replicate this in vb using the 'System.Data.SqlCommand' but cannot get the return values! the clr stored procedure uses the Pipe.Send to return the data.

> result = ex.Message;
>               SqlContext.Pipe.Send(result.ToString());

Would I be better using an output parameter in the sp or should I be able to get this value?

Comment: If it is always going to be a single value you can use an output parameter. However, if you are expecting multiple values or table values then return a  table from the SP and catch it in the output in your c# code.

Comment: I have added the output parameter to the clr stored procedure as

Comment: I have added the output parameter to the clr stored procedure as 'ref SqlString Result' when I add the output parameter cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", "TestResult")
            cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output to the .net method making the call I get an unexpected result I get the value 4 If I replace the string "TestResult" with an integer value say -1 I get an error which states that 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
41124|4032|Ok' what is the correct parameter type to pass in?

Comment: Not sure why you opened a new question that is really a duplicate of this only a few hours after opening this one, but you should close this one since you do now have a duplicate that has more info on it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50530270/577765

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Error converting data type nvarchar to int" when executing Stored Procedure and reading return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530270/error-converting-data-type-nvarchar-to-int-when-executing-stored-procedure-and)