# "Error converting data type nvarchar to int" when executing Stored Procedure and reading return value

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, return-value, sqlclr

I have a clr stored procedure which has an output value I am calling the sp from a vb.net app with the code below.  I am getting an error that says 'Error converting data type nvarchar to int.
1125092|63688|Ok' the values are exactly what I am expecting back from the sp but I can't understand why I am getting a convertion error can anyone help with this.

Code Calling the sp:

```
Try
            Dim CN As New SqlConnection
            CN.ConnectionString = My.Settings.myConnection
            CN.Open()

            Dim Profile As String = "40T"
            Dim StartPosition As String = "53.6924582,-2.8730636000"
            Dim Destination As String = "46.18186,1.380222"
            Dim RetValue As String = "Testvalue"

            Dim test As String ="53.816408201,-2.990582799997"

            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GetDistanceAndTime", CN)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "GetDistanceAndTime"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profile", Profile )
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartPosition", StartPosition)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", Destination)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Result", SqlDbType.NVarChar )
            cmd.Parameters("@Result").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            Try

             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                RetValue = cmd.Parameters ("@Result").value
                If RetValue .Length > 2 Then

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(Err.Description)
        End Try
```

The clr sp code:

```
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void SqlStoredProcedure1(SqlString Profile, SqlString StartPosition, SqlString Destination, ref SqlString Result)
    {
        SqlString result;
        try
        {           
            SqlPipe sqlPipe = SqlContext.Pipe;

            result = DistanceRequest.InvokeService(Profile.ToString(), StartPosition.ToString(), Destination.ToString());
            Result = result.ToString();          
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(result.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(result.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

Oddly when I execute the stored procedure from sql server manager it compiles the return value as an int!  I am even more baffled.

```
USE [myDB] GO

DECLARE @return_value int, @Result nvarchar(50)

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[GetDistanceAndTime]
  @Profile = N'40T',
  @StartPosition = N'53.6924582,-2.8730636000',
  @Destination = N'46.18186,1.380222',
  @Result = @Result OUTPUT

SELECT  @Result as N'@Result'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Please always post the full and exact error message, not just part of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**The main problem is with this line:**

```cs
AddWithValue("@Result", SqlDbType.NVarChar )
```

The problem is that `SqlDbType.NVarChar` is an `enum` yet is being used incorrectly here as the "value" to imply the datatype from. The datatype is, by default, `int`. This is why you are getting an error converting the stored procedure's `Result` parameter into the `int` that was declared for the `SqlCommand` parameter via the line shown above.

**A secondary problem is:**

While I have nothing against calling Web Services from within SQLCLR, it should only be done when the process is wholly contained within T-SQL. If you are in .NET code already, it makes no sense to execute a stored procedure only to call a Web Service. That is highly inefficient, for both the app layer and the DB layer.

**Several other things:**

1. Your .NET code returns `void` from the method, so no use capturing `@return_value`
2. Don't use the `AddWithValue` method. Instead, create each parameter with the correct datatype and then set the value, then add it to the `Parameters` collection.
3. Even though this was already mentioned as the problem, regarding creating parameters like this in the future, even using `Add`: 
   `AddWithValue("@Result", SqlDbType.NVarChar )`
   When setting the datatype to a string type, be sure to also set the maxsize / length
4. This could be a problem:
   `RetValue = cmd.Parameters ("@Result").value`
   `SqlParameter` values are of type `object`. So either cast to string or add `.ToString()` to `value`.
5. You don't need to call `ToString()` on the `SqlString` input parameters. All `Sql*` types have a `Value` property that returns the value in the expected .NET type. Meaning, `Profile.Value` returns the string you are looking for.
6. You create `SqlPipe sqlPipe = SqlContext.Pipe;` but never use it. You could use it in both places that you are doing `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()`. So, instead use: `sqlPipe.Send()`.